# Tshark: invalid option -- '-'

Tags: tshark

I am trying to run the command

```bash
sudo tshark -r tmp.pcap --disable-protocol dcp-etsi --disable-protocol dcp-pft -t e -E separator=, -T fields -e frame.number -e frame.time_epoch -e data.data > tmp.out
```

However, I am getting the error

```
Tshark: invalid option -- '-'
```

My Tshark version is

```
$ tshark -v
TShark 1.10.14 (Git Rev Unknown from unknown)
```

Where is this problem occurring? Is it because of version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your version of `tshark`/Wireshark is much too old.  The ability to disable protocols from the command line wasn't added until July 17 2015 with this commit: https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/commit/ad82dfd5547e460359eb3597ddb6760a29c40439.

The first Wireshark release with new features after this date was Wireshark 2.2.0 (Ref: https://www.wireshark.org/news/), so that's almost certainly the minimum version required that supports that option.

Comment: How would I properly update tshark to handle this version?